# Can I disable the attack animations?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I'm planning to buy Ni No Kuni on my PS3. I've played the demo from the PSN Store, but there's one thing that I don't like too much that seems present in most RPGs: the attack animations.

After 20+ hours playing the game, it's very boring for me to watch the attack animations before every fight, as well as the fanfare played at the end of fights.

Is it possible to disable the attack animations in Ni No Kuni?

Comment: Are you referring to the transition animation you get before the battle starts?

Comment: Yeah, you need to be more clear about what you are asking. I have clocked up 30+ hours so far and I have never noticed anything annoyingly repetitive at the start of each battle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several stages to getting into a fight:

- Bump into a monster on the world map
- Transition/load screen as the fight starts
- Your team runs in (short animation)
- You select a character/familiar and it is thrown out (another short animation)

None of this is skippable, although you can speed it up slightly by mashing buttons to bypass any waiting for user input.

After the fight:

- The camera switches to displaying one or more of your characters (short animation #3)
- The EXP, gold, and loot are tallied on one screen
- Any level ups are shown as separate screens (prompting you for trick choices if you level up and are out of tricks)
- Transition back to the world map

You can skip ahead during any of the top three parts by mashing the X button over and over again.  There's a minimum amount of time, but it's fairly short.  None of these can be completely disabled either.